# What's the difference between FFKM and PTFE?

Tags: halides, polymers

These two fluorocarbon polymers seem to me very similar, the only difference I see is that FFKM is elastomer while PTFE aka Teflon is more of hard type of plastic.

Isn't FFKM just PTFE with lower average molecular weight, that is the average molecule is shorter chain so its softer? Is the production of these two polymers vastly different or is the process mostly same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teflon (PTFE) and Kalrez (FFKM) are different polymers.

PTFE is made from tetrafluoroethylene, and contains only carbon and fluor. 
The material is stiff.

FFKM is made from tetrafluoroethylene, vinylidene fluoride and perfluoromethylvinylether, so besides carbon and fluor, it also contains hydrogen and oxygen. 
These additional monomers make the polymer an elastomer.

Comment: Is it possible to make elastomer from just carbon and fluorine atoms?

Comment: I am not sure. Parofluor, another trademark FFKM polymer, does not use vinylidene fluoride, so it does not contain hydrogen. But oxygen is still there. There are elastomers made with only carbon and hydrogen containing monomers so, theoretically, it should be possible by using the equivalent perfuorinated compounds.

Comment: Kalrez is much more common in industrial applications.

Answer (score 1):

FFKMs don't contain any hydrogen. FKMs does. TFE/HFP (FEP) copolymers aren't elastomeric due to the high Tg (by far above room temperature)

Comment: Would you mind spelling out the acronyms?

Comment: PTFE stands for PolyTetraFluoroEthylene. FFKM isn't an acronym. Its definition is given by ASTM D1418: "Perfluorinated rubbers of the polymethylene type
having all fluoro, perfluoroalkyl, or perfluoroalkoxy substituent
groups on the polymer chain"